# Why isn't the address of consecutive array entries, also consecutive?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

When I run

```
char * a = "string";
char * b = a;
while (*a != '\0')
    printf("%p %c\n", *(a), *(a++));
printf("%p\n", *(b+2));
```

The output looks like

```
0x73 s
0x74 t
0x72 r
0x69 i
0x6e n
0x67 g
0x72
```

Also,how does the program figure out that (b+2) is located at 0x72. I thought it would just add 2 to the starting address of b, in this case 0x73.

Edit: This isn't a case of unspecified behaviour. As explained in the answers, I was mistakenly passing the value to the address format specifier instead of the pointer itself.

Comment: ...that's may because of  undefined behavior!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are these constructs (using ++) undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior)

Comment: @Olaf; Not exactly. It has something new.

Comment: @haccks: Too bad we can only show one dup. Feel free to add the UB for wrong type specifier in the format string :-)

Comment: Have a look at an [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII)-table and compare to the output you show. Notice something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
printf("%p %c\n", (void *)a, *a);
a++;
```

and rejoice, consecutive elements are actually consecutive!

What was wrong in your code:

- when you wrote `*(a)` you passed to `printf` the *value* of the current character instead of its address, which was then printed by `printf` as if it was a pointer; the hex values you saw are the character codes of the characters of `"string"` instead of their address (notice that passing to `printf` different arguments from expected from the format string is undefined behavior, the fact that it produced somewhat sensible output is accidental);
- the second `printf` is also affected by the same error;
- you'll notice that here I also separated the increment in a separated statement; as *haccks* pointed out, as they originally were you also had *another* cause of undefined behavior, since a function call doesn't introduce sequence points between the evaluation of its arguments; this means that it's undefined which one is evaluated first, and so whether `a` is incremented before or after the second argument to `printf` is evaluated.
- using `char *` instead of `const char *` for pointers to string literals is deprecated;

Comment: @haccks: sorry, I missed it at first. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You don't print addresses but characters. `a` is an address, `*a` is the value (of type `char`) stored at that address. `0x73` is the [ASCII code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S#Computing_codes) of lowercase `'s'` and so on.

If you want to print addresses then your code should look like:

```
char * a = "string";
char * b = a;
while (*a != '\0') {
    printf("%p %c\n", a, *a));       // address and value (char)
    a ++;
}
```

Also, `printf("%p\n", *(b+2));` prints the value of `b[2]` which is lowercase `'r'` ([ASCII code `0x72`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R#Encoding))